# Does FORWARD traffic that gets redirected(PREROUTING) pass through the FORWARD(filter) chain?

Tags: networking, router, iptables, forwarding

Good day,

Does traffic that gets redirected by the nat PREROUTING chain to the localhost then still pass the FORWARD filter chain? Example:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Does traffic from another host (thus forwarded traffic) that passed through the first rule still pass through the FORWARD chain and thus get dropped by the second rule? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - couldn't find much elsewhere so I set up some LOG targets and it seems that when traffic gets jumped to the REDIRECT chain it does not pass through the FORWARD(filter) chain.